# /dev/mapper/centos_server2-root is full

Tags: centos, directadmin

i have a problem with centOS and DirectAdmin,
i can't login to panel, because not space available for create session

when i run df -h command, get the following result:

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_server2-root   50G   50G   20K 100% /
devtmpfs                         7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            7.8G  8.6M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       1014M  143M  872M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos_server2-home  192G  124G   68G  65% /home
tmpfs                            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

how i can free up /dev/mapper/centos_server2-root ?

Comment: Run a `sudo du -xsh /*` and check what's causing a 100% full FS. Once you know, try removing it.

Comment: @iamauser thank you, /var/log using 46GB disk space

Comment: FWIW, don't remove the directories, just the old log files. Some apps that do their own logging don't understand how to create the log directory, since it's done by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the old logs from your system.

For removing old log files, are your logs being rotated, e.g. do you have /var/log/messages, /var/log/messages.1, /var/log/messages.2.gz, etc, or maybe /var/log/messages-20101221, /var/log/messages-20101220.gz, etc?

The obvious way to remove those is by age, e.g.

# find /var/log -type f -mtime +14 -print

# find /var/log -type f -mtime +14 -exec rm '{}' \;

Found out here https://serverfault.com/questions/215179/centos-100-disk-full-how-to-remove-log-files-history-etc (by mikel)

Note: Use the rm command with cautious.